# Mysql SET type and multi data process with php in sql query

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I've been trying to create a search form on my website that depends on what the user check ( checkboxes), I've spent many time researching on web but didn't find anything, so I had to do things myself.
so here is the code for the html

```
<li><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="action"> Action</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Adventure"> Adventure</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Animation"> Animation</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="cars"> Cars</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="cartoon"> Cartoon</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="comedy"> Comedy</li>
```

and here is the php

```
<?php

     if(!empty($_POST['checkbox'])) {

        $Gen3 = implode(" AND * ", $_POST['checkbox']);

     $Gen2= str_replace('*', 'Genre like ', $Gen3); 

                $table='animelist';

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table  WHERE Genre like '".$Gen2."' ORDER BY NAME DESC" ;  

                echo $sql;
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die('Erreur SQL !'.$req.'<br>'.mysql_error());

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

?> 

<li><a href="Anime.php?/anime=<?php echo $row['Name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></a></li>

<?php ;
}
};
?>
```

the echo $sql if I check two checkboxes for example result

```
SELECT * 
FROM animelist 
WHERE Genre like 'action AND Genre like Adventure' 
ORDER BY NAME DESC
```

so the thing here is that the "movie" that the user would research might be a SET of "Action,Adventure" , so when the user checks the checkboxes the result have to be the "movies" which are both Action and adventure not only Action.

for now if I only check one checkbox evrything works fine but when I check two or more I get nothing

so I though that the ' in the sql query before and after the variable are the one ruining it, so I had to get ride of them, so I tried to use  mysql_real_escape_string, but since its not accepter anymore and the mysqli_real_escape_string doesn't do the job I am stuck here.

Comment: Nobody uses the SET type. Pretend it doesn't exist

Comment: and what should I use instead ?

Comment: looked for that, I  cant see where is it going, and the only type that may be like SET type is ENUM  , and its the same thing I believe

Comment: Yes, it requires some thought and attention - but pays dividends in the end

Comment: the problem is that ENUM can have only one value

Comment: Which is why I suggest normalisation as the correct course of action - assuming your interest in using an RDBMS for the storage and retrieval of data continues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey I solved it by using FIND_IN_SET

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for a genre named 'action AND Genre like Adventure' where you should be doing somehting like

```
SELECT * 
FROM animelist 
WHERE Genre like 'action' OR Genre like 'Adventure' 
ORDER BY NAME DESC
```

Thats for your question, but you should use prepared statements to prevent SQL Injection and use = instead of like whenever possible.

Comment: I did, a few times more actually, specially after your comment. You are defining a $Gen2 var which has SQL, but you are treating all the $Gen2 as a string, not SQL. Therefore MySQL returns nothing when more than a genre is selected. There is no genre like 'action AND Genre like Adventure'. As you are sending the query MySQL searches for a genre named like that whole string.